# This formula is in Output Text, how do I have output in number?

Tags: sales

`FORMATDURATION((EX3_Tempo_TMA__c.EX3_Hora_fim_do_tratamento__c-EX3_Tempo_TMA__c.EX3_Hora_inicio_do_tratamento__c)*24*60*60)`

They are given strings, with the formula above these data come out in text, only I want it to come out in number keeping the format of strings, because then I'm going to group and make the subtotals by groups.

Comment: Using an example of real dates, could you explain what you are expecting your output to be?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to provide some clarity. As fred asked, what sort of output are you after? What units should this number have?

Comment: São dados strings, com a formula acima esses daos saem em texto, só que eu quero que saia em numero mantendo o formato de strings, porque depois eu vou agrupar e fazer os subtotais por grupos.

Comment: Please stick to English. I'm myself not a native speaker, but this website is English-only.